# How to use easy-thumbnails with static in template?

Tags: python, django, easy-thumbnails

I wonder how (if it is possible) load thumbnail for static files with [easy-thumbnails](https://pypi.org/project/easy-thumbnails/) package.

I tried:

```
<img src="{% thumbnail 'img/V.png' 50x0 %}" />
<img src="{% thumbnail static 'img/V.png' 50x50 %}" />
<img src="{% static thumbnail 'img/V.png' 50x50 %}" />
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registered tag filters for **easy-thumbnail** package are not implemented in a way to render images from the static directory directly. Rather it expects an instance of **Image/FileField** model ([Doc Reference](https://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#thumbnail-tag)). But you can implement your own filter, redirect the url to static directory and use it based on your needs.

Here, you can adopt one of the following strategies as well.

```
{% load static thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail image 50x50 crop="center" as thumb %}
{% if thumb %}
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}{{ thumb.url }}" width="{{ thumb.width }}" height="{{ thumb.height }}" alt="" />
{% else %}
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/V.png" alt=""/>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% load static thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail object.image|default:'{{ STATIC_URL }}img/V.png' 50x50 %}
```

or by using a custom tag filter to redirect the url of the image instance, if you use `S3 bucket instance` for static files.

`settings.py`

```
S3_ROOT_PATH = "<define your S3 hosting path>"
```

`teamplatetags/s3static`

```
from settings import STATIC_URL, S3_ROOT_PATH

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def s3_static_thumb(image_instance=None):
    return "{s3_root_path}{static_path}{image_url}".format(s3_root_path=S3_ROOT_PATH, static_path=STATIC_URL, image_url=getattr(image_instance, "url")) if image_instance and hasattr(image_instance, "url") else None
```

finally, use that in your template:

```
{% load static thumbnail s3static %}

{% with image|s3_static_thumb as im_url %}
   {% thumbnail image "720x306" crop="center" %}
   {% if im %}
       <img src="{{ im_url }}" width="{{ image.width }}" height="{{ image.height }}" alt=""/>
   {% else %}
       <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/V.png" sizes="50x50" alt=""/>
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.